# How to share an Amazon EB instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, web-applications, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, instance

I am currently using an Elastic Beanstalk environment for my web application. I have created an instance within it and I can deploy easily each new versions of my app.

Do you know a way to share this instance with another worker ? In order to allowing him to deploy from his laptop ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use AWS IAM service and create an account for this other user.

Assign him permission for AWS Beanstalk and AWS S3. This is sufficient to allow him deploy on beanstalk.